# Get commit list between tags in git

Tags: git

If I've a git repository with tags representing the versions of the releases.

How can I get the list of the commits between two tags (with a pretty format if is possible) ?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

`git log --pretty=oneline tagA...tagB` (i.e. three dots)

If you just wanted commits reachable from tagB but not tagA:

`git log --pretty=oneline tagA..tagB` (i.e. two dots)

or

`git log --pretty=oneline ^tagA tagB`

Answer (score 35):

To compare between latest commit of current branch and a tag:

```
git log --pretty=oneline HEAD...tag
```

Answer (score 32):

`git log` takes a range of commits as an argument:

```
git log --pretty=[your_choice] tag1..tag2
```

See the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) for `git rev-parse` for more info.

Answer (score 25):

To style the output to your preferred pretty format, see the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats) for `git-log`.

Example:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h; author: %cn; date: %ci; subject:%s" tagA...tagB
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider also this:

```sh
git range-diff tagA...tagB
```

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff

Answer (score 4):

FYI:

```
git log tagA...tagB
```

provides standard log output in a range.

Answer (score 4):

If your team uses descriptive commit messages (eg. *"Ticket #12345 - Update dependencies"*) on this project, then generating changelog since the latest tag can de done like this:

```
git log --no-merges --pretty=format:"%s" 'old-tag^'...new-tag > /path/to/changelog.md
```

- `--no-merges` omits the merge commits from the list
- `old-tag^` refers to the previous commit earlier than the tagged one. Useful if you want to see the tagged commit at the bottom of the list by any reason. (Single quotes needed only for iTerm on mac OS).