# GitHub REST API: Commits per release

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to obtain the commits that were included on an specific release, on a repository that uses tags to identify releases. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863426/get-commit-list-between-tags-in-git), this doable through `git log`.

However, I need to gather this information for several repositories, so using an API is more convenient. Is it possible to get that information from GitHub's REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [compare two commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits):

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/compare/:base...:head`

This is the same as locally running `git log base..head`.

Given that you want to automate this for several repos check [List your Repositories API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) as well

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: According to the documentation, base and head must be branch names. Does it work with tags?

Comment: I'm not sure if the documentation chose the word `branches` because it's more mainstream. If it accepts references then yes: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References

Comment: Works like charm! The only problem is that it only returns 250 commits max. Do you know another way that doesn't have that limitation?