# How to get the list of branches that made the difference between 2 git revisions

Tags: git

I git tag every production release. It would be nice if i am able to know the branches merged into the repository between the latest production code with the previous release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a script:

You can start by [listing commits between two (release) tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5863452/6309):

```
git log --pretty=oneline tagA..tagB
```

Here: commits reachable from tagB but not tagA, with tagB being more recent than tagA.

For each commit, you can [check if it is a merged commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3824050/6309):

```
git show --no-patch --format="%P" <commit hash>
```

If this is not empty (there is a parent commit merged), you can [see the branch(es) part of that parent commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309).

```
git branch --contains <commit>
git branch -r --contains <commit>
```

Answer (score 0):

You check the branch merge and nesting in graph by this :

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```