# Github GraphQl - How to get a list of commits between tags

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

With Github GraphQL I want to answer the question:

> What commits have been merged into master between releases/tags?

The result should be similar to the results for this question [Get commit list between tags in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863426/get-commit-list-between-tags-in-git) if I were to do it on the command line.

I'm using the developer explorer and wondering if I will be able to do this with a single query or if I will need several. I tried the following but it does not give me the commits between tags that have not been tagged, just the tagged commits.

```
{
  repository(owner: "CoolCompany", name: "awesome-new-ui") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", first: 2, orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: DESC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          target {
            oid
            ... on Commit {
              author {
                date
                email
                name
              }
              message
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This may not be possible via GraphQL, but in v3 it's straightforward: `https://api.github.com/repos/CoolCompany/awesome-new-ui/compare/A...B` where `A` and `B` are any git reference

Answer (score 1):

@lee-dohm from the Github GraphQL community helped me arrive at a solution which is posted [here](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/GraphQL-How-to-get-a-list-of-commits-between-tags-or-releases/m-p/25142)

I can paste my solution here as well. It seems this problem is not solve-able with a single query, but it can be done with 2 that work in conjunction with each other:

Step 1: Get the most recent release information. You could modify this for tags as well.

```
{
  repository(owner: "CoolCompany", name: "awesome-ui") {
    releases(last: 1) {
      edges{
        node{
          tagName
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2: Use the value from the createdAt (associated with the release or tag) and do this:

```
{
  repository(owner: "CoolCompany", name: "awesome-ui") {
    nameWithOwner
    object(expression: "master") {
      ... on Commit {
        oid
        history(first: 100, since: "$createdAtDate") {
          nodes {
            oid
            messageHeadline
            author {
              user {
                login
              }
            }
            committedDate
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```